# Why are part of my model differently colored?

Tags: modeling

I tried to redo normals, but this doesn't seem to be the issue here. When imported to Unreal the different colored items have missing polies.

[image]

Comment: You need to recalculate normals, select that part of the model in edit mode and hit CTRL+N

Comment: I tried to recalculate the normals, but it stays that way...

Comment: Ok, great guys! I forgotten to select all surfaces before re-calculating. This issue seems now to be resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy, recalculate the normals of the oddly colored area of the model. the normals look like they have been reversed.

Comment: Recalculating doesn't change the color. How can i reverse the objects?

Comment: In the Shading/UVs panel, under normals section use Flip Direction