# Missing Faces when importing to Ue4 and Unity

Tags: import, unity

So I just finished modelling my Scar H but I noticed this it has some blue and white parts in it and when I import it to UE4 and Unity half of the blue parts was gone am I doing something wrong?

In UE4 when I import it it says "the model has degenerate tangent which may cause incorrect shading"

Comment: Most likely flipped normals, double edges, double vertices or edges with more than 2 faces connected.

Comment: Yeah maybe but how to fix it?

Comment: [Quick google on the exact error message](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/159072/47-degenerate-tangent.html) shows UE4 forum posts about dealing with it, may be worth reading

Comment: Blender.StackExchange is here to spread knowledge which can be used by more than just one person. If you care to [share the .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or can localize the problem area and just share that part in a .blend, then we can rewrite the question to include something that people can cross reference (before, and after) if they get that error too. Else this question might be considered too narrow and get little attention. Which would be a shame.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27347/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6651/599

Comment: but how to share the blend file

Comment: there's a link in my previous comment.